# tab completion not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, input, windows-10, readline

I'm trying to create a prompt with tab completion. I have two files. main.py and prompt.py. main.py imports prompt.py and runs prompt.py's `main()` function. The `main()` function sets up a tab completer using readline and repeatedly waits for user input. It prints whatever is inputted and should have tab completion which completes according to whatever text is in the COMMANDS list.

main.py:

```
import prompt
prompt.main()
```

prompt.py:

```
import readline
import colorama
colorama.init()
COMMANDS = ['qwerty','uiop','asdf','ghjkl']

def complete(text, state):
    for cmd in COMMANDS:
        if cmd.startswith(text):
            if not state:
                return cmd
            else:
                state -= 1

def main():
    readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete")
    readline.set_completer(complete)
    while True:
        test_input=raw_input(':')
        print test_input

main()
```

What should happen is when I press the tab button the program tries to autocomplete to whatever is in the COMMANDS list. So if I type in "qwe" and press tab the program tab completes to "qwerty". However when I press tab in the program, nothing happens.

Upon commenting the line `colorama.init()`, the code can now autocomplete. So the line `colorama.init()` is affecting tab completing. Why is this so? How can I run that line without it affecting the tab as I need the colorama module to output colored text on the windows command prompt.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't even run: that makes it hard to help. Have you tried using `def main():` instead of `def main`?

Comment: sorry that was a typo

Comment: Both pyreadline and colorama make extensive use of the Windows console API via ctypes, so it's possible they're conflicting, either in how they use the console or something to do with ctypes itself if they're sharing global state (e.g. by using `ctypes.windll`).

Comment: Thanks. I've also added `main()` to the end of the code so it will run. I edited your question to add inline-code formatting (take a look to see how I did it). I'm running Linux and can't reproduce your problem, so I'm not otherwise much help here. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `readline` uses the standard output stream, which is equivalent to `sys.__stdout__`, to control the terminal.

However, when you call `colorama.init()`, Python's default stream, `sys.stdout`, is redirected to `colorama`'s own wrapper.

`readline` then no longer sees the unadulterated standard output and fails to function. Notably, `colorama` strips the special escape codes that `readline` uses.

This problem will also occur if you manually redirect `sys.stdout` - for instance to apply your own formatting or send output to a GUI.

The solution in all cases is to restore `sys.stdout` to the default, `sys.__stdout__`, for the duration of any `input`, for instance via:

```
original_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
foo = input()
sys.stdout = original_stdout
```

Note that `colorama`s OS-indenpendent colouring features now won't work during this `input`, so if you want colours in your input prompt, you'll have to branch and make the relevant escape calls for your supported platforms (Windows/Unix) independently.